How do I fix a 404 Error in Vercel/Github?
I started a very simple project using only Html, Css and Vanilla JS. When I deployed it to Vercel, first it worked and then it just gave me an error (404 Not Found). As the project is still in its infancy, I started from scratch, created a new repo and tried to deploy it again, but the same error still occurs.
As a note, my old projects from other repos are still visible. What could be the possible error?
Link to Preview
I've already tried restarting the project from scratch, with a new repo.
I have a new Mac and since I started using it, Vercel doesn't work. However, my old projects that I only have on Github are still visible on Vercel.

https://quizz-app-khaki.vercel.app/home seems to work, the vercel.json changed and broke the index page

I think you are missing the routing of vercel.json. create a vercel.json file in the root of the repo with the following content
{
"rewrites": [
    {"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"}
]
}

and push to the repository.

Unfortunately not. I've added the json file, made a new PR, but I still can't see the project. Any other suggestions as to where the error might be?  What confuses me is that I always get: “This branch was successfully deployed”. If it helps... Repo: https://github.com/Larissartoricader/QuizzApp

I needed this vercel.json file:
    {
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.html",
      "use": "@vercel/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "styles/*",
      "use": "@vercel/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "scripts/*",
      "use": "@vercel/static"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}

and also to install vercel:
npm install -g vercel

The result isn't what I expected it still looks total different than my local version, but I don't see the 404 anymore:
